# Used Enum in Class Constructor, Method Within Class Won't Recognize Reference Variable

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I'm taking a CSIS 1410 Class, and as part of an assignment, I needed to create an enum, Voltage. Then, I had to create a class that uses the enum as a parameter, but when attempting to use the reference variable voltage (lowercase v), it gives me error "voltage cannot be resolve to variable". 
Here is the enum:

```
public enum Voltage
{
    V110, V220, DUAL;
}
```

and here is the class using said enum

```
public class DeskPhone extends Phone
{
    public boolean connected;

    protected DeskPhone(String modelArg, Dimensions dimenstion, Voltage voltage) //enum as parameter
    {
        super(modelArg, dimenstion);
    }

    public void plugIn()
    {
        connected = true;
    }

    public void unPlug()
    {
        connected = false;
    }

    public boolean isConnected()
    {
        return connected;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if(connected == false)
        {
            return super.toString() + " " + voltage + " not connected"; //results in error
        }

        return super.toString() + " " + voltage + " connected";

    }
```

Why can't I store whatever the constructor is passed within the "voltage" variable and use it in my toString statement?

Comment: Could you add the class definition of Phone as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you have never declared voltage field, you only pass it as argument to constructor.

```
public class DeskPhone extends Phone
{
    public boolean connected;
    // Here we declade voltage as field
    public Voltage voltage; 

    protected DeskPhone(String modelArg, Dimensions dimenstion, Voltage voltage) //enum as parameter
    {
        super(modelArg, dimenstion);
        // Here we set field value
        this.voltate = voltage;
    }
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Although now I feel especially stupid haha. I'm reading off of a UML diagram and I didn't see the "-voltage" on the association arrow, so I was trying to follow that to a T.

Answer (score 1):

because constructor arguments are only visible inside a constructor
you need to bind them to a class field to be able to use them in functions:

consider also using Lombok for less boilerplate

```java
public boolean connected;
private Voltage voltage;


 protected DeskPhone(String modelArg, Dimensions dimenstion, Voltage voltage) 
 {
  super(modelArg, dimenstion);
  this.voltage = voltage;
 }
```